# Lazy loading loads navigation properties without sql query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

we were looking into the difference between Lazy Loading and Eagerly Loading in Entity Framework.
we were looking for the SQL Query that entity creates.
we have Province model like this:

```
public class Province
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<City> City { get; set; }
}
```

if we use **Eagerly Loading** and we wanted that Country Property and City Property is filled with data, then Entity creates and SQL Query like this (we use **.include("PropertyName Or Expression")** to load country and city) :

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
[Project1].[Name2] AS [Name2], 
[Project1].[ProvinceId] AS [ProvinceId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name2], 
    [Extent3].[ProvinceId] AS [ProvinceId], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Province] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Country] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CountryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[City] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[ProvinceId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[Id1] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

and when we use **Lazy Loading** it generate SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId]
    FROM [dbo].[Province] AS [Extent1]
```

and we still have access to country and city for the province.
my question is **how can Lazy Loading fill country and city property without mentioning them in SQL Query?** (we used both Visual Studio and SQL Profiler to get the SQL Query in both scenarios)

Comment: It runs an extra query, after the first one. You'll see it if you run a SQL Trace.

Comment: @mjwills i've tested it and you're right.it runs extra query when i use that property.i have one more question.if i have a list<province> with 20 item in it, if i put them in a foreach loop and add the country property into list<country> , does entity runs 20 different query or 1 query for all of the country objects?

Comment: Test it and find out, however the answer is it will search memory first before loading again

Comment: i'm not THAT familiar with Lazy Loading cause i'm used to raw sql query but now that i've run my test for lazy loading i know that it send a request for EACH item in iteration and causes a lot of sql query requests.but thank you both @mjwills and GertArnold